# Adding text to beginning of each array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which contains the contents as follows:

```
["ZS125-48ATab", "STR125YBTab", "KS125-24Tab", "ZS125-50Tab", "DFE125-8ATab", "ZS125-30Tab", "HT125-8Tab", "HT125-4FTab", "STR50Tab"]
```

Is it possible to append a `#` symbol to the front of each element in the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]="#"+array[i];
}
```

Comment: `
array.forEach(item => {
   item = "#" + item
})
`

Answer (score 62):

Example for ES6

```
var arr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];    
arr = arr.map(i => '#' + i);
```

Result:

```
console.log(arr); // ["#first", "#second", "#third"]
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 21):

Iterate over the array and just add `#`

```
var arr = [your array];

for (var i=arr.length; i--;) {
    arr[i] = '#' + arr[i];
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zNeH4/)

In newer browsers you could do

```
arr = arr.map(function(e) {return '#' + e});
```

Comment: I can understand when newcomers do that, but I don't think high-rep users should answer "questions" like this. A closevote (+ a friendly "what have you tried" comment) would be a way more helpful.

Comment: @thg435 - seems like a legitimate question to me, even if it's not something that's really hard to do, or figure out with a little trial and error.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: @thg435 - That is true, and if you feel it should be closed, vote for that, that's up to you.

Comment: Of course I did, and downvoted yours. "Gimme some codez" questions as well as "gimme some repz" answers don't belong here.

Comment: @thg435 This question is clear and not so surprising coming from a newcomer, I think it deserves a little help. Why not posting a comment to explain the rules?

Answer (score 12):

Simple & sweet in ES6 as,

```
array.map((line) => `#${line}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
array = ('#' + array.join('#')).match(/#[^#]*/g) || []; // null || []
```

The following trick works as well, but I wonder why `split` ignores the first sharp...

```
array = ('#' + array.join('#')).split(/(?=#)/);
```

Indeed, I rather expected this scenario : `"#a#b#c" -> ["", "#a", "#b", "#c"]`.

Anyway, I prefer the second method since `match` returns `null` in case of failure.

Comment: @acostache Trickier but probably more expensive :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `forEach` method([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

```
var array = ["ZS125-48ATab", "STR125YBTab", "KS125-24Tab", "ZS125-50Tab", "DFE125-8ATab", "ZS125-30Tab", "HT125-8Tab", "HT125-4FTab", "STR50Tab"];
array.forEach(function(element, index) {
    array[index] = '#' + element;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code would do the job:

```
var t = ["ZS125-48ATab", "STR125YBTab", "KS125-24Tab", "ZS125-50Tab", "DFE125-8ATab", "ZS125-30Tab", "HT125-8Tab", "HT125-4FTab", "STR50Tab"];

    for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        t[i] = "#"+t[i];   
    }
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5hfPx/2/)