# How to add a dot before each item in this list of array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this: `const array = ['jpg', 'png]`.

Right now I can join them like this:

`array.join(',')` to produce: `jpg,png`

What the simplest way of getting something like this:

`.jpg,.png` (addid a bot before each item?)

Comment: `const types = array.map(mime => "."+mime)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20498409/3244407

Comment: `array.map(prefix('.'))`. Now you just have to write `prefix`.

Comment: Surely you could've gotten as far as `'.' + array.join(',.')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods:

```
array.map(function (fileExtension) {
    return '.' + fileExtension;
}).join(',');
```

Fat arrow notation is also acceptable (and short!)

```
array.map(extension => '.' + extension).join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ['jpg', 'png'];
const extensions = array.map((item) => `.${item}`).join(',');

console.log(extensions);
```